# Android Stock Browser downloads file immediately after start

Tags: malware, stock-browser

Android 4.4.2 Kitkat Stock Browser

If I start it or open new tab, downloading of apk file (xb_client_blah-blah-blah.apk) from site no.stepfaster.com immediately starts instead of opening page which is set as default.

Obviously some malware fixed Browser's config. Which file and how to fix this?
No root. Browser was stopped and cache cleaned several time. Nothing was installed before this. The mentioned site contains AdSDK apk-files.

Comment: Did you clean the browser data also? I think you need to first find which app is responsible

Comment: Button "clear data" in Application manager is grayed out for Browser. 
What do you mean under "which application is responsible". Responsible for what?

Comment: Related on Android Central Forums: [Android Tablet Browser - Keeps Downloading Suspicious Web Address](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/827817-android-tablet-browser-keeps-downloading-suspicious-web-address.html)

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after asking the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I had this today.

I cleared the download manager cache and rebooted, but the problem persisted.

I then re cleared the download manager cache AND the stock browser cache, rebooted and the issue had stopped.

Comment: I did the same before and repeated today with no luck. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared not only the cache but also the data of the browser. Then I deactivated it.

Then I cleared the cache of the application launcher. I tracked down and removed the apk in Download. If you click on them before removing them, you can see what the app has access to.

I rebooted. I activated Browser again. I rebooted again. Now it works fine. It stopped downloading apk when opened. I may be still infected by the previous apk, though.